# Can you explain what's association relation in database?

Tags: database, associations, foreign-key-relationship

I thought it was alias for simple **foreign key relation**,but seems not.

Can you take MySQL as an example what is **association relation**?

I guess it means many2many relation,is that true?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You confuse `relation` and `relationship` here. These are different concepts.

An association relationship is a class theory concept. This is a relationship between two or more entities that does not imply any limitations on their life cycles.

Say, friendship is an association relationship: a person can be a friend to one or more persons, but when the friendship ends, no actual persons are erased from existence.

In relational databases, this is usually represented with a many-to-many link table with `FOREIGN KEY` references to the tables holding primary keys of the entities associated.